# Date search in Access Query not showing results

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT tblTeam.TeamName, tblFixtures.FixtureDate
   FROM tblTeam 
      INNER JOIN tblFixtures 
         ON (tblTeam.TeamID = tblFixtures.Team2) 
            AND (tblTeam.TeamID = tblFixtures.Team1)
  WHERE (((tblFixtures.FixtureDate) Between #1/1/2018# And #3/1/2018#));
```

Hi, I am trying to make this query for my database but it dsoesn't seem to show any result. I tried it in Design view on access too but this query doesn't seem to work, No results show up at all.

It is just a small database I have created on the fixtures table there are Team1 and Team2 and the date of the fixture, Team1 and Team2 are FKs from The Team Table.

[Data from Fixtures Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4utV.png)

[Data from Team Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drOOw.png)

Comment: Without data, how can we tell? Maybe there just isn't any data which matches the query

Comment: Just curious as to why those brackets in `(tblFixtures.FixtureDate)`

Comment: Sorry I added an image not to show the data, I tried removing them brackets and nothing seemed to work, I tried following information online and also tried making the query using query design both didn't seem to work

Comment: "mysql" tag but "Access Query" in the title. Can we clarify what DB we're using, please? Looks like Access from the SQL, but...

Comment: Access DB The tag was auto set I didn't even notice the tag section

Comment: I see the image for Fixtures.....  what about tblTeam data?

Comment: Without looking into it too much - wouldn't you need to pull in `tblTeam` twice to the query?  At the moment you're telling it that `TeamID` must be equal to `Team2` and `Team1` at the same time.

Comment: I'm still trying work queries out so I'm completely new to all of this, I tried adding in TeamName twice in the query design but that didn't work either.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook -- just Answered it that way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're after (images are blocked here).

You basically need two lists of teams - the Home team and Away team.
To return a list that (probably) mirrors your fixture list but using team names rather than identifiers you'd use:

```
 SELECT T1.TeamName
        ,T2.TeamName
        ,FixtureDate
 FROM   (tblFixtures INNER JOIN tblTeam T1 ON tblFixtures.Team1 = T1.TeamID)
                     INNER JOIN tblTeam T2 ON tblFixtures.Team2 = T2.TeamID
```

Another possibility is that you just want a single list of teams and any dates they're playing.  You'd need a `union` query to pull both Home & Away teams into a single field:

```
SELECT TeamName, FixtureDate            
 FROM   tblFixtures INNER JOIN tblTeam ON tblFixtures.Team1 = tblTeam.TeamID
 WHERE  FixtureDate BETWEEN #01/01/2018# AND #03/01/2018#

 UNION SELECT   TeamName, FixtureDate            
 FROM   tblFixtures INNER JOIN tblTeam ON tblFixtures.Team2 = tblTeam.TeamID
 WHERE  FixtureDate BETWEEN #01/01/2018# AND #03/01/2018#
```

**Edit:**

- There's no need to list the table name in the SELECT clause if there's no ambiguity to which table the field came from.
- Access goes way over the top with brackets.  E.g. `(tblFixtures.FixtureDate)` in your SQL.

Answer (score 2):

The join you have right now

```
ON (tblTeam.TeamID = tblFixtures.Team2) 
            AND (tblTeam.TeamID = tblFixtures.Team1)
```

is expecting the ***same team for both Team1 and Team2*** in Fixtures.

Since this is never true, you get no rows.

If you're trying to lookup information on *each team* in tblTeam, you need to use **two joins**.
As in:

```
FROM (tblFixtures AS tf
    INNER JOIN tblTeams as tm1 on tf.Team1 = tm1.TeamId)
    INNER JOIN tblTeams as tm2 on tf.Team2 = tm2.TeamId
```

Notice the different "tm1" and "tm2" - this is how it works to understand clearly the two copies of the same table.
When you use the values from tblTeams, be sure to use those prefixes to talk about the right Team.  Access is pretty good about reminding you once you put them in the FROM.

To put the whole query together, then, would look like:

```
SELECT tm1.TeamName, tm2.TeamName, tf.FixtureDate
FROM 
    (tblFixtures as tf 
        INNER JOIN tblTeams AS tm1 ON tf.Team1 = tm1.TeamId)
        INNER JOIN tblTeams tm2 ON tf.Team2 = tm2.TeamId
WHERE (((tf.FixtureDate) Between #1/1/2018# And #3/1/2018#));
```

Comment: Okay, This makes a little bit of sense to me, so I just need to add the above instead of what In the FROM section?

Comment: That's all of the FROM... after the "SELECT tblTeam.TeamName, tblFixtures.FixtureDate" , and before the "WHERE".

Comment: Ahh I see thank you, When use that for the full query it comes up saying that there is an syntax error, Missing operator in query expression 'tf.Team1 = tm1TeamId INNER JOIN tblTeams AS tm2 on tf.Team2

Comment: ugh :-p.  Ok.  I'll have a look.  Or we could both have a look and see who catches it :) .  In your comment, there's the  "."  missing..... it's not that, is it?

Comment: I copy and pasted a few times to make sure nothing was missed as well as typing it out double checking it all so nothing was missed Im trying to work it out at the moment thanks for the help :)

Comment: The answer below has printed out the fixtures between Two Dates in a different way but I think this will be OK for my tutor I will find out tomorrow Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: You need to add the brackets on the first join in Access otherwise you'll get a syntax error `FROM (tblFixtures AS tf INNER JOIN tblTeams AS tm1 on tf.Team1 = tm1.TeamId) INNER JOIN tblTeams AS tm2 on tf.Team2 = tm2.TeamId `

Comment: You're welcome.  I did fix it now.  I forgot some mandatory parentheses.  **embarrassed**  It's getting late over here and I couldn't catch that easier part.  Sorry about that

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  --  yes!  I was just updating the answer...   big little "oops" there

Comment: Notice the brackets appear on your answer just as I was about to hit enter.... didn't want to waste the time I'd spent writing the comment so posted anyway... should've deleted it really. :)

Comment: Yes, it was funny timing.  I appreciate the communication.  It keeps SO moving :)